# inserting text into a specific line

Tags: bash

I've got a text file, and using Bash I wish to insert text into into a specific line.

Text to be inserted for example is `!comment: http://www.test.com` into line 5

```
!aaaa
!bbbb
!cccc
!dddd
!eeee
!ffff
```

becomes,

```
!aaaa
!bbbb
!cccc
!dddd
!comment: http://www.test.com
!eeee
!ffff
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it in place for a large number of files?  Or once for a single file?

Answer (score 21):

```
sed '4a\
!comment: http://www.test.com' file.txt > result.txt
```

i inserts before the current line, a appends after the line.

Comment: what does the 4a mean?

Comment: I'm curious why this doesn't work (without a new line after \ ): `sed '4a\!comment: http://www.test.com' file.txt > result.txt` I get the following error: `extra characters after \ at the end of a command`

Comment: Looks like sed requires an explicit newline or `\'$'\n`. Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991275/escaping-newlines-in-sed-replacement-string#comment-11267604

Comment: Thank you! An excellent way to insert license headers in XML files in a compliant way (nothing shall come before XML preamble), for example https://gist.github.com/berezovskyi/467320e305871498d0acdc32c6f269a2

Comment: @m4l490n I suppose `4a` means "4 after" (place the text after the 4th line on line 5). It worked in my case. Be aware that if you need to run the same command multiple times, the previous string does not get replaced, it just moves one line further (line 6 in our case).

Answer (score 4):

you can use awk as well

```
$ awk 'NR==5{$0="!comment: http://www.test.com\n"$0}1' file
!aaaa
!bbbb
!cccc
!dddd
!comment: http://www.test.com
!eeee
!ffff
```

Answer (score 2):

Using man 1 ed (which reads entire file into memory and performs in-place file editing without previous backup):

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed
line='!comment: http://www.test.com'
#printf '%s\n' H '/!eeee/i' "$line" . wq | ed -s file
printf '%s\n' H 5i "$line" . wq | ed -s file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file in place and add the string (let's say cookie) in the line you want with:

```
sed -i '5i\cookie' MyFile
```

Please be aware that:

1. The line has to already exist in the file even if empty.
2. If you use the command multiple times, the old string does not get deleted in order to be replaced by the new one. It moves one line further.