# escaping newlines in sed replacement string

Tags: bash, unix, sed, escaping, solaris

Here are my attempts to replace a `b` character with a newline using `sed` while running `bash`

```
$> echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\n/'
anc
```

no, that's not it

```
$> echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\\n/'
a\nc
```

no, that's not it either. The output I want is

```
a
c
```

HELP!

Comment: This works for me the way you want it on Ubuntu 11.10 with GNU sed. What version of sed are you using?

Comment: echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\n/' works fine on my bash on Debian (Wheezy). My bash version: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). My sed version: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: Not sure, manpage doesn't say and `sed -V` doesn't work, but I'm on SunOS 5.10

Comment: On Solaris, you can get the POSIX compatible 'sed' by setting this path: PATH=/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/css/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you are on BSD or Solaris. Try this:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\ 
> /'
a
c
```

Add a black slash and hit enter and complete your `sed` statement.

Comment: Yes! But why do I need the \ before I hit enter?

Comment: Once I realized he was on Solaris I tried the manual-`Enter`, but forgot the backslash at the end of the line. Good catch.

Comment: @spraff Solaris sed is extremely dated, and requires an explicit newline instead of a `\n`.

Comment: Explicit newline I get, but why the backslash before it?

Comment: @spraff The backslash is a way of telling `bash` "continue this command on the next line". You can do it with any `bash` command when you want to split it up for clarity.

Comment: @DanFego Thanks Dan! Trust me I hate working on `solaris` boxes at work after getting used to `GNU` goodies. :)

Comment: @DanFego Thanks again. Yes @spraff, `backslash` at the end is a way to tell the shell to hold on, there is more stuff coming on the next line. :)

Comment: @DanFego I use explicit lines in unescaped single quotes in bash at home on Ubuntu and never backslash-prefixed. Which is exceptional, Ubuntu or Solaris?

Comment: @spraff Solaris is UNIX and Ubuntu is an offshoot of Debian which is Linux. If you add a back slash on your Ubuntu machine it would still work. Since Solaris adheres to POSIX standards if you ever wish to make a script that would work across different platforms adding a backslash will be useful

Comment: If you have bash then you should also be able to write it like this, even on Solaris, and have it work: `echo abc | sed 's/b/\'$'\n'/` - the advantage here is that you don't have that pesky significant newline, which makes copying and pasting easier. `$'\n'` is a bashy way to insert literal escape sequences. By the time `sed` sees it it's the same as Jaypal's version.

Comment: Also: In this case the backslash is NOT being interpreted by bash, but rather by sed. `sed` requires that newlines in the replacement pattern be escaped with \. Consider this: `(set -x ; echo abc | sed "s/b/\$PATH/")` which shows that `bash` has interpreted `\$` and `sed` sees only `$`, vs this: `(set -x ; echo abc | sed 's/b/\'$'\n'/)` which shows that `bash` has expanded `$'\n'` but left the \ before it to `sed`. For comparison try running `echo abc | sed "s/b/\"$'\n'/` and see what you get.

Comment: When I do this on SunOS 5.10 I get the error `sed: command garbled: s/b/\`

Comment: @sorpigal - please post your upvoted comment as a separate answer, as it's better than most of the others.

Comment: This method is the POSIX-approved way to insert newlines ("[A line can be split by substituting a <newline> into it. The application shall escape the <newline> in the replacement by preceding it by a <backslash>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03)"). As demonstrated by the question, using `\n` instead of a literal newline is not portable.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\'$'\n''/'
a
c
```

In Bash, `$'\n'` expands to a single quoted newline character (see "QUOTING" section of `man bash`). The three strings are concatenated before being passed into sed as an argument. Sed requires that the newline character be escaped, hence the first backslash in the code I pasted.

Comment: Nice answer! `echo 'abc' | sed $'s,b,\\\n,'` is even clearer, I think.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say you want to globally replace all <kbd>b</kbd>. If yes, you want `tr` instead:

```
$ echo abcbd | tr b $'\n'
a
c
d
```

Works for me on Solaris 5.8 and bash 2.03

Answer (score 1):

In a multiline file I had to pipe through tr on both sides of sed, like so:

`echo "$FILE_CONTENTS" | \
 tr '\n' ¥ | tr ' ' ∑ | mySedFunction $1 | tr ¥ '\n' | tr ∑ ' '`

See unix likes to strip out newlines and extra leading spaces and all sorts of things, because I guess that seemed like the thing to do at the time when it was made back in the 1900s. Anyway, this method I show above solves the problem 100%. Wish I would have seen someone post this somewhere because it would have saved me about three hours of my life.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 'abc' | sed 's/b/\'\n'/'
```

you are missing `''` around `\n`

Comment: just tested on ubuntu 11.01 and it works. my bash version is GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu) and sed version is 4.2.1

Comment: Works for me on bash 4.3.42(1)

Comment: this is just another way of writing the first command in the question and it will fail on BSD-ish and Solaris versions of sed in exactly the same way