# Switching first word of paired lines using sed

Tags: sed, line, switch-statement

What I want to do exactly is switch the first word of paired lines using `sed`. I know this could be easier using something else, but sed is required unfortunately (testing myself)

So, and example would be

```
One line here
Two line here as well
Third line could be here
fourth line to end
```

would end up being

```
Two line here
One line here as well
fourth line could be here
third line to end
```

I might have been using the wrong operation in `sed` but yeah, no idea. any clues?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 'N; s/\([a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)\n\([a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\   ⏎
\1\4/'
```

(yes, that is an explicit line break escaped by a backslash in the substitute)

Comment: +1 But why don't you write a literal `\n` in the replacement string, as `\3\2\n\1\4/`? It's easier to read for me.

Comment: Yes. In a linux shell the output is the same in both cases.

Comment: Which shell ? (ps -p $$)
In bash/zsh/sh/csh, with those quotes, the \n escapes to the n letter. The escape I suggest is [somewhat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421478/how-do-i-use-a-new-line-replacement-in-a-bsd-sed) [standard](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch34_08.htm) [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991275/escaping-newlines-in-sed-replacement-string).

Comment: From your last link I understand that is not a shell issue. Mine is `bash`, but the `\n` use in replacement wouldn't work in `BSD` and `Solaris`, regardless of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (probably GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\(\S*\)\(.*\n\)\(\S*\)/\3\2\1/' file
Two line here
One line here as well
fourth line could be here
Third line to end
```