# replacement for cut --output-delimiter

Tags: bash, awk, solaris, cut

I created a script that was using

```
cut -d',' -f- --output-delimiter=$'\n'
```

to add a newline for each command separated value in RHEL 5, for e.g.

```
[root]# var="hi,hello how,are you,doing"
[root]# echo $var
hi,hello how,are you,doing
[root]# echo $var|cut -d',' -f- --output-delimiter=$'\n'
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

But unfortunately when I run the same command in Solaris 10, it doesn't work at all :( !

```
bash-3.00# var="hi,hello how,are you,doing"
bash-3.00# echo $var
hi,hello how,are you,doing
bash-3.00# echo $var|cut -d',' -f- --output-delimiter=$'\n'
cut: illegal option -- output-delimiter=

usage: cut -b list [-n] [filename ...]
       cut -c list [filename ...]
       cut -f list [-d delim] [-s] [filename]
```

I checked the man page for 'cut' and alas there is no ' --output-delimiter ' in there !

So how do I achieve this in Solaris 10 (bash)? I guess awk would be a solution, but I'm unable to frame up the options properly.

Note: The comma separated variables might have " " space in them.

Comment: If you want the same cut command you have on RHEL, install the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about using `tr` for this?

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <<< "$var"
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

or

```
$ echo $var | tr ',' '\n'
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed 's/,/\n/g' <<< "$var"
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

Or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '1' RS=, <<< "$var"
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

Comment: Somehow I'm feeling like a BIG DUMBO!!! I never thought of using 'tr' or 'sed'...pfffttt..... Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: 'sed' didn't work, 

bash-3.00# echo $var|sed -e 's/,/\n/g'
hinhello hownare youndoing

but 'tr' worked!

Comment: Uhms I don't have a Solaris server to test, but maybe in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991275/escaping-newlines-in-sed-replacement-string you can find some clues. And good to read `tr` was fine for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps do it in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) itself?

```
var="hi,hello how,are you,doing"
printf "$var" | (IFS=, read -r -a arr; printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
hi
hello how
are you
doing
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I would prefer something smaller also I would like not to use an array for this.