# Automatically convert fixed length strings into delimited strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have many files containing such lines :

1. HUIHOJ OPKKA LK
2. ASOIJS AISJJ PL
3. AOSKSI ASIJD YA

I want to convert theses lines into something like this :

1. HUI;HOJ ;OPKKA ;L;K
2. ASO;IJS ;AISJJ ;P;L
3. AOS;KSI ;ASIJD ;Y;A

So the first field would be 3 characters, second would be 4, third 6, fourth 1 and fifth 1 character.

I know that it's possible to do it manually with excel, but I need to have automatically conversion solution, because I have many files with exactly the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA has a simple command to format text, so you can do this fairly easily, and with just a single line of code

```
Function SpFmt(S As String) As String
    SpFmt = Format(S, "@@@\;@@@@\;@@@@@@\;@\;@")
End Function
```

If you want to use a worksheet function, you can do this with a nested replace formula on the worksheet:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,4,0,";"),9,0,";"),16,0,";"),18,0,";")
```

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realize you could use REPLACE to just insert a string like that, by using '0' for the length being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use the VBA [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) after splitting ([Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx)) on a space or simply replace ([Replace functoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) all of the spaces with a space & semi-colon.

```
dim str as string

str = range("A1").value2   'HUIHOJ OPKKA LK
range("A1") = Join(Split(str, char(32)), chr(32) & chr(59))  'HUIHOJ ;OPKKA ;LK

str = range("A1").value2   'HUIHOJ OPKKA LK
range("A1") = Replace(str, chr(32), chr(32) & chr(59))  'HUIHOJ ;OPKKA ;LK
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bounded to Excel, you can use unix tools (also [available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)) to do this very efficiently with just one command:

```
cut --output-delimiter=";" -c 1-3,4-7,8-13,14,15 fixed.txt > delimited.csv
```

The same command in a loop:

```
for f in *.txt ; do
  cut --output-delimiter=";" -c 1-3,4-7,8-13,14,15 "${f}" > "${f}.csv"
done
```

Edit : the output delimiter option does not seem to work on every platform.

Alternatively, you can use `sed` :

```
sed "s/^\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{6\}\)\(.\)\(.\)/\1;\2;\3;\4;\5/" fixed.txt > delimited.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on osx it will be perfect. I tried your command on a file named fixed.txt, but I get an error : "cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]"

Comment: Ok, the osx version of cut may have slightly different options than on Linux. It doesn't seem to support the --output-delimiter option. You should refer to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cut.1.html).

Comment: Same issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195728/replacement-for-cut-output-delimiter. You may have to replace default output delimiter.